# Java initializing classes without repeating myself

Tags: java

Is it possible to rewrite the following a bit more concise that I don't have to repeat myself with writing `this.x = x;` two times?

```
public class cls{
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;
    public int z = 0;

    public cls(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public cls(int x, int y, int z){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

BoltClock's answer is the normal way. But some people (myself) prefer the reverse "constructor chaining" way: concentrate the code in the most specific constructor (the same applies to normal methods) and make the other call that one, with default argument values:

```
public class Cls {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int z;

    public Cls(int x, int y){
         this(x,y,0);
    }

    public Cls(int x, int y, int z){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

Comment: I usually make this last constructor private or protected, so I can control the ways to get there.

Answer (score 10):

Call the other constructor within this overloaded constructor using the `this` keyword:

```
public cls(int x, int y, int z){
    this(x, y);
    this.z = z;
}
```

Comment: And it is called "constructor chaining "

Answer (score 1):

Read about constructor overloading
http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-constructors

Answer (score 0):

You can use initilization block for this purpose.

Comment: @Nikita Rybak This isn't code golf - the idea isn't to make the code as short as possible, just to stop duplication which can lead to overlooking changes to the code in the future - ie changing one constructor but not the other.

Comment: @Noel I just don't understand what's proposed to do, that's all.

Comment: @Zacky I'd advise against dynamic initializers, they make code less obvious and readable to others.

Comment: @Noel M I think Nikita's "11 more characters" was to get his post up to the minimum length, not a comment about the length of the code.

Comment: Ah, sorry Nikita, my misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

Very simple: Just write an initialize function like this:

```
public class cls{
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;
    public int z = 0;

    public cls(int x, int y){
       init(x,y,0);
    }

    public cls(int x, int y, int z){
       init(x,y,z);
    }

     public void init(int x, int y, int z ) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;  
    }
}
```

Comment: the trouble with this is that you can't make the variables final and you also can't make sure that init can be called from constructors only.

Comment: It would be better to make the init method private. But the selected answer does the same, with less code.

Comment: @seanizer Your right - but the OP dident tell us if he need the code elsewhere, just that he don't want to repeat. So i dident bother about such things, and dident use constructor chaining. @Alexandre Your right too, see my comment for seanizer.